# Is it possible to recover ADA sent to wrong address?

Tags: ada

I have sent the ADA token to FTX using BNB network. But FTX doesn't support the ADA token. Is is possible to recover/retrieve the ADA token?

Thanks.

Comment: To which address you had sent the ADA if it was not supporting? If you have the address use cardanoscan to find the transaction. It is not possible to retrieve unless the address owner can be found and he send it back.

Answer (score 2):

If querying the chain (either directly through CLI or using an explorer like cardanoscan) shows that ADA has been sent outside of any wallet to which you have the signing keys, you no longer have access to that ADA. Plain and simple. :|

The only workaround is if the receiving address decides to send it back to you.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if one day someone can create a website where you can just input the address the crypto was sent to and dispute the charge proving if the coins are yours or not. What a simple world that would be lol but then again it’s a decentralized world sadly.